# If $$ is the vector, what does the $_1,...,_n$ refer to?

Tags: linear-algebra

I really have no clue how to word my (admittedly quite basic) question.

Take the definition for Linear Combinations (from Friedberg, Insel and Spence):

> Let $S \subseteq V$ (any subset). A vector $v$ is a linear combination of $S$ if there are $a_1, ..., a_n \in \mathbb F$ and $v_1,..., v_n \in V $ such that $v=a_1v_1+...+a_nv_n = \sum_{i=1}^n a_iv_i$

If $v$ is the vector, **what does the $v_1,..., v_n$ refer to?** (Smaller, sub-vectors???) What do I visualize?

Comment: I think the statement is : "A vector $v\in V$ is a linear..."

Comment: $V$ is a vector space - not a vector - and $v_1,..., v_n$ are a basis vectors.

Comment: Another possible typo: $v_i\in V$ should be $v_i\in S$ to make more sense.  And the lower index in the summation sign should be $i=1$.

Comment: $S$ is a collection of vectors. $v_i\in S$ for all $i$ ($S$ may not be finite.) But think of $\mathbb R^3$, with the vectors $v_1,v_2,v_3$ as the standard unit vectors (1,0,0),(0,1,0),(0,0,1). Then we write any point in $\mathbb R^3$ as $c_1*v_1+c_2*v_2+c_3*v_3$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your statement has overused the letter $V$ and has a mistake in the statement.  A corrected statement to make it clearer which v stands for which:

> Let $\color{red}{\mathbb{V}}$ be a vector space over the scalar field $\mathbb{F}$.  Let $\color{green}{S}\subseteq \color{red}{\mathbb{V}}$ (any subset).  A vector $\color{blue}{v}$ is a linear combination of $\color{green}{S}$ if there are $a_1,\cdots, a_n\in \mathbb{F}$ and $v_1,\cdots, v_n\in \color{green}{S}$ such that $\color{blue}{v} = a_1v_1+\cdots + a_nv_n$.

The set of all such vectors $\color{blue}{v}$ such that they can be written as linear combinations of vectors from $S$ is called the [linear span of $S$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_span).

As for an example... suppose that our vector space is $\Bbb R^3$ over the scalar field $\Bbb R$, a rather common example that you should be used to.

Let $S = \{(1,1,0),(0,1,0),(1,-1,0)\}$.  To make naming schemes clear, from here out I will refer to the vector $(1,1,0)$ as $v_1$, the vector $(0,1,0)$ as $v_2$, and the vector $(1,-1,0)$ as $v_3$.  These vectors $v_1,v_2,v_3$ are each vectors from the set $S$.

> In other examples, we might not have bothered to explicitly name each vector, we might have many more than just three vectors in $S$, and we might not even have the *ability* to name each vector due to how many there are.  But, the point being, the vectors exist and we have the option to name as many of them as are needed at the time of their use.

Now... if we were curious about a particular vector $\color{blue}{v}$ such as if $\color{blue}{v}=(2,1,0)$ and we ask to see if it is in the linear span of $S$, i.e. if it is a linear combination of $S$, we look to see if there are appropriate choices of $v_1,v_2,v_3$ and real numbers $a_1,a_2,a_3$ such that $\color{blue}{v}=a_1v_1+a_2v_2+a_3v_3$.

Indeed, $(2,1,0)=2\cdot (1,1,0) + -1\cdot (0,1,0)+0\cdot (1,-1,0)$, i.e. in my example $\color{blue}{v}=2v_1+(-1)v_2+0v_3$ so $(2,1,0)$ *is* a linear combination of $S$ in my example.

On the other hand, in my example you should be able to see that $(0,0,1)$ is *not* a linear combination of the $v_1,v_2,v_3$ I gave earlier since every linear combination of those will wind up with the third entry always equal to zero and can never have third entry equal to $1$.

As you continue your studies, you will learn how to further classify and distinguish between those choices of $S$ that have certain special properties (*such as being a [basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basis_(linear_algebra)) for a space*).